# No. of linearly independent bounded solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $V$ be the set of all bounded  solutions of the ODE

> $u''(t)-4u(t)=0$   $ where$ $t \epsilon \Bbb R$. Then $V$ is
>
> a)real vector space of dimension 2
>
> b)real vector space of dimension 1
>
> c)contains only trivial solution $u=0$
>
> Here I've got the solution as $y=$ ${ae^{-2x}}$ $+$ ${be^{2x}}$
> .If we take $V$  as the set of all solutions of the given ODE then option a) will be true.But here $V$ is defined as the set of ***bounded solutions***.So what is the no. of linearly independent bounded solutions?Also u=0 is a solution of the given ODE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $y=ae^{-2x}+be^{2x}$ to be bounded.

For $x \to +\infty$, $e^{2x} \to +\infty$, so you have to set $b=0$.

For $x \to -\infty$, $e^{-2x} \to +\infty$, so you have to set $a=0$.

Thus, $0$ is the only  bounded solution.

Comment: I just realized i forgot $x \to -\infty$ :)

Comment: Oh, yes... So $0$ is the only solution.

Comment: I made the same mistake hah. Indeed, so used to see negative exponential always going to 0. ^^